# Why doesn't "papeterie" have an accent mark on the "e"?

Tags: orthographe

The pronunciation seems to be \pa.pɛ.tʁi, \pa.pe.tʁi\ or \pap.tʁi. Other than the third one, which is probably the least common, judging by the order, doesn't the "e" require an accent to denote that it is not a /ə/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally there is no accent in *papeterie* ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/papeterie), [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/papeterie/57755)) despite its different pronunciations ([papεtʀi], [-pe-], [paptʀi]). The spelling of some [words](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3190#LettreP) was [reformed in 1990](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifications_orthographiques_du_fran%C3%A7ais_en_1990) ; the *accent grave* [was added](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=3176) at that time. Both spelling are accepted and correct. Furthermore, in this case you use the diacritic to reflect your actual pronunciation. [Ac.9](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9P0395) says that the word is *often* pronounced like « pè » i.e. [ε]. With [paptʀi] some sound is dropped or compounded, just feels to me like a quicker pronunciation of [papetʀi], but this has no bearing on the spelling.

Comment: In France, I always heard it pronounced *papètri*, and never *paptri*

Comment: @XouDo Je n'ai jamais entendu paptʀi non plus, ça vient du TLF. Autrement, entre  pa.pɛ.tʁi et pa.pe.tʁi, j'ai entendu les deux dans mon coin. Le fait qu'on ait ajouté l'accent témoigne probablement d'une évolution dans la direction de papεtʀi.